# How to show a web page in full screen mode without statusbar and addressbar in all browsers?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery

How to show a web page in full screen mode without statusbar and addressbar in all browsers and it should not show the taskbar also.

Comment: You want to force the user into full screen mode?

Comment: Yes,i want to force the user into full screen mode.

Comment: Then all we need to do is add some graphics to the page to mock up what looks like a normal browser window, with an address bar that looks like a popular bank, and we can go on a phishing expedition. There's a reason that this is impossible in modern browsers.

Comment: I am doing it for in-house application

Comment: Try deploying Google Chrome in [application mode](http://superuser.com/questions/33548/how-to-start-chrome-in-application-mode) in your organization.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do this with JavaScript - and that's a *good* thing...I don't want a full screen advertisement in my face, do you?

Pseudo-out-of-browser plugins can do some of this though, Flash and Silverlight for example...but you can't do it with just a page and JavaScript.  Browsers (especially newer ones) actively prevent most resizing and windows-without-bars behavior.

Comment: Then how this code works for Internet Explorer? I need the for Firefox and Safari..      window.open("b.html", "secondWindow", "fullscreen,scrollbars='no',statusbar='no',menubar='no',resizable='no',titlebar='no'").focus(); window.self.close(); window.opener = 'secondWindow';

Comment: @user455423 - That's the part I meant by "especially newer ones", IE9 prevents this better than others...IE allowed a lot of things, that doesn't mean it was ever right.

Answer (score 1):

If **I** want **MY** browser to be in full screen mode, **I** will press F11.

It is **MY** browser. Not yours.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, as Javascript can only change things inside the webpage. It cannot change the behaviour of the browser itself.

Comment: Then how this code works for Internet Explorer? I need the  for Firefox and Safari..    window.open("b.html", "secondWindow", "fullscreen,scrollbars='no',statusbar='no',menubar='no',resizable='no',titlebar='no'").focus();
window.self.close();      
window.opener = 'secondWindow';

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in javascript. The reason is that someone might make a screen that looks like a windows lock screen and force users to type in their username/password. Its called phishing and illegal : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing . For right usage you can ask the user to opt into it (the user has to click a button) using Silverlight / Flash. However in this case the keys that function are limited. So you cannot get the user to type alphanumeric keys. Keys commonly used in games (e.g space / arrow keys) will function. So will mouse clicks. With Silverlight if the user accepts you application to be Trusted (FullTrust) you can even capture all keys : http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/11/18/whats-new-in-silverlight-4-complete-guide-new-features.aspx

Comment: Okay. But to prevent Phishing the browser's javascript engine does not contain any api to do this :) You can make a fulltrust silverlight application that will do this though.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get what really you wants?
You want code to your page OR manually you want to do with browsers.

If while browsing you want to do IE, Mozilla, Google chrome etc. will Do it with "F11" key (Short cut key)

**(Highly NOT RECOMMENDED, but you can try** **)**If you want javascript for this, here it is...

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function fullScreen(theURL) {
window.open(theURL, '', 'fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=auto');
}
</SCRIPT>

<--- BODY OF DOCUMENT -->

<body onload="fullScreen('popup_webpage.htm');">
```

this will open the webpage in new pop-up on page load.

Comment: This won't work for firefox ..It is showing address bar and taskbar of your system.I want full screen.

Comment: it works...  just leave firefox for 2 sec, address and task bar automatic hides, when u move mouse either top or bottom it appear again. It is browser feature...